# Node + Sequelize: How to check if item exists before adding? (async confusion)

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, sequelize.js, async.js

I am unfortunately new to node and running into some confusion regarding the asynchronous/synchronous execution of node.

I am using node, sequelize with sqlite and async.js.

I have a series of `Articles`, each of which has a number of `Authors`.

For each `Authors` in each `Article`, I'd like to check if the `Author` exists. If not, create it.

The problem is, on the initial run, duplicate authors are being created, I assume due to asynchronous functionality causing an issue with checking for existence.

For example, with the array: `authors = ['A. Test', 'B. Test', 'C. Test', 'A. Test']`

and the code:

```
async.each(authors, function(item, callback){
    Author.sync().then(function(){
      Author.count({ where: {name: item.trim()} }).then(function(count){
        if (count != 0) {
          console.log('Author already exists')
        } else {
          console.log('Creating author...')
          Author.create({
            name: item.trim()
          })
        }
      })
    })
  })
```

On the first run, will create a table:

```
ID | name
------------
0  | A. Test
1  | B. Test
2  | C. Test
3  | A. Test
```

What am I doing wrong? I seem to be missing a fundamental concept of asynchronous vs synchronous execution in Node.

(I've also tried async.eachSeries which is supposed to execute in series rather than in parallel?)

**Edit: Slightly refactored, but still creating duplicates**

```
async.eachSeries(authors, function(authorName, callback){
    Author.findOne({ where: {name: authorName.trim()} }).
    then(function(author){
      if (author) {
        // Author exists...
        callback()
      } else {
        // Author does not exist...
        Author.create({
          name: authorName.trim()
        }).then(function(author){
          callback()
        })
      }
    })
  })
```

Answer (score 36):

`Author.count` isn't really needed, unless you **need** the count. See [findOrCreate()](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/model/#findorcreateoptions-promiseinstance-created).

With `findOrCreate()` you could have the following. (Edited trex005's snippet for this)

```js
async.eachSeries(authors, function(item, callback) {
  Author.sync().then(function() {
    Author.findOrCreate({
      where: {
        name: item.trim()
      },
      defaults: { // set the default properties if it doesn't exist
        name: item.trim()
      }
    }).then(function(result) {
      var author = result[0], // the instance of the author
        created = result[1]; // boolean stating if it was created or not

      if (!created) { // false if author already exists and was not created.
        console.log('Author already exists');
      }

      console.log('Created author...');
      callback();
    });
  })
})
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, actually I tried `findOrCreate` (and refactored to a somewhat cleaner snippet added to my answer above) but `findOrCreate` was causing all sorts of issues with sqlite blocking/database locking - apparently this was happening in postgres for some users as well. Unfortunately, my new snippet still doesn't actually work, and is still creating duplicates.

Comment: @joshua-f btw, you can use spread method instead of then method for seperating promise arguments. Example: `.spread(function(author, isCreated) { ... });`

Comment: @AliBARIN Oh sweet, did not know that.

Comment: Is there a reason for calling sync() inside the async function?

Comment: @RonenTeva No, that should probably be outside of the async function.

Answer (score 0):

Change your each to `eachSeries` and actually call the callback and you should be golden.

```
async.eachSeries(authors, function(item, callback){
    Author.sync().then(function(){
      Author.count({ where: {name: item.trim()} }).then(function(count){
        if (count != 0) {
          console.log('Author already exists')
          callback(); //assuming you want it to keep looping, if not use callback(new Error("Author already exists"))
        } else {
          console.log('Creating author...')
          Author.create({
            name: item.trim()
          }).then(function(author){
            callback();
          })
        }
      })
    })
  })
```

Comment: Hm, this doesn't appear to be working, it's only adding the first author.

Comment: Does your Author.create support a callback like I mentioned in the comments?

Comment: Sorry, how do you mean? The `create` method is [implemented by sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/model/#createvalues-options-promiseinstance) which results in a promise

Comment: Ok, it works, thankyou! Just to clear my understanding of the flow, what is the `callback()` function that is called? I find the wording of the [async.js documentation](https://github.com/caolan/async#each) confusing.

Comment: It tells the loop to continue

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately after further testing, the function it is still creating duplicate results :(